# How Do I Make this contact form work?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I am not able to edit this 'contact us' form code work and deliver messages to my mail-box.

Say I wanted to get messages delivered to my email: doherty@noob.com, how do I edit this code do the task?

```html
<div class="conatct-form">
   <ul class="form">
    <li>
    <input type="text" class="text" value="Name*" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name*';}" >
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="text" class="text" value="Email*" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email*';}" >
    </li>
    <li>
    <textarea value="Message*:" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your Message*';}">Message*</textarea>
    </li>
    <div class="sub-button">
     <input type="submit" value="SEND">
    </div>

   </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Well, this is probably because the above code is _not_ a html `<form>`, but a simple `<div>` container. Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: And the form would have to have some php code that would take the form values, create an email, and send it.

Comment: please add your code insted of image so we can give you idea where you are doing mistake and we can give you correct code currently issues with you have not any form tag add form tag and add action.

Answer (score 1):

I've optimized your code and added some PHP code

PHP code

```
 <?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    if (isset($name, $email, $message)) {
        // Insert into database
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts ...");

        if ($query) {
            // send email using phpmailer, sendmail, ...
            mail($mail, 'Subject', $message, '...');
        }
    }
?>
```

HTML

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <!--
                Substituting the code below
                <input type="text"
                       value="Name *"
                       onfocus="this.value=''"
                       onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name *'}" />

                use the placeholder attribute instead
            -->
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name *" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email *" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message *"></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your HTML inputs in a  element in order for proper form to work.

Thus, you'll need the following tag:

```
<form action='url_to_submit_to' method='POST' enctype='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'>

 <!-- Rest of your code here -->

</form>
```

See the Mozilla documentation for more details on the format and arguments of the `<form>` tag:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Answer (score 0):

Here submit is not happening because the content is not wrapped inside a form tag.
All the content should be wrapped inside  tag which has action attribute to some php/java file which validate the data passed by user and commits to database.

Please check form tag on mdn for more information.

Comment: So all I am missing is one "form tag"  and some php which is supposed to be inserted in between the form . Is it?

Answer (score 0):

rather than you using
    if (isset($name, $email, $message)) {...}
there HTML5 'required' will be better in your tags. e.g
    
Also, you submit type needs to have a name. the name will be used to process your form.

Answer (score 0):

contact.php page. the form below processes itself since the method is its name, contact.php.

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" >
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
<input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject *" />
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email *" />
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Message *"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="send"/>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['send']))  {
$to = "youremail@something.com";
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = $_POST['email'];
$headers = "From: $from $name";
$sent = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

if ($sent)  {
echo "<p style = 'color: #00ff00;'>Message was sent.</p>";
}
else    {
echo "<p style = 'color: #ff0000;'>Message was not sent.</p>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried copy pasting the code you shared. Typed my email instead of youremail@something.com but it resulted in error. Here's the screenshot to what I see my webpage as http://postimg.org/image/7zfzsuj0h/
What am I doing wrong?

And this is what I copied: http://postimg.org/image/uvawpbyrl/

Comment: Hey sorry for late reply. First u have to save the page with name contact.php